# Safe to store OAuth2 token in cookie?

Tags: php, cookies, oauth, google-oauth

I am developing a website that uses one's Google Account to log into the site. The site goes through the process of obtaining the OAuth2 token and logs the user in. However, after a short amount of time my site forgets the token in its session variables (PHP) and therefore logs the user out. I need to store the OAuth2 token for a longer period of time but I'm not sure where to store it securely. If I store an OAuth2 token in a Cookie does it open the site up to any security risks?

Comment: Persistent database storage is a good enough for storing tokens. What't the problem ?

Comment: I'm storing the token in PHP session storage as a way for the site to know if a user is logged in or not (if they are it can refer to the token to look up account information). My issue is that the session variable is getting unset after about 10 minutes, so I need an alternative way for the site to remember that the user is logged in.

Comment: There is some discussion here that may be helpful: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/50986/oauth2-authorization-save-token-in-the-cookies-or-in-the-session